# c# - IDENT_CURRENT in Linq-to-Entities

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am using Linq-to-Entities in my Windows Application and want to execute this SQL statement:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ('ProductInfo') AS Current_Identity
```

I have read another post that is using `Database.SqlQuery` like this:

```
int varMaxAdvertiseId = Convert.ToInt32(hmd.Database.SqlQuery<decimal>("Select IDENT_CURRENT ('HMDAdvertiseManage')", new object[0]).FirstOrDefault());
```

but this is not working with me (intelisense is not showing it) Can someone help me, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    var id = hmd.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(@"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ({0}) AS Current_Identity;",
"HMDAdvertiseManage").First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.0 to 4.8 then you should be careful that your model usually inherit from `DbContext` then when you want to use `ExecuteStoreQuery`
then you should get `ObjectContext` from your model

```cs
var context = new YourDbContext();
var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)context;
var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
var id = objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<decimal>(@"SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ({0}) AS Current_Identity;", "HMDAdvertiseManage").First();
```

every things is Ok now